# How can I get the name of an Ember Class?

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to grab the classnames of views as they are rendered and add them to an array in my controller. Is there anyway to get the classname from the `this` object in Ember?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this.$()` gives you your current view's element, you can grab the `classList` off the first instance.

```
App.IndexView = Em.View.extend({
  didInsertElement: function(){
    console.log(this.$()[0].classList);
  }
});
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/xicopadi/1/edit